# Pagination not keeping the page state between page navigation

Tags: angularjs, dirpagination

I have implemented pagination using dirPagaination. There is a click action which actually hides an icon in a row. When I came back to the current page after visiting the 2nd and 3rd page, the hidden icon is showing.

Answer (score 0):

use `<pagination>` tag. it is very easy to add paggination functionality in angular js.

```
totalItems = total records
currentPage = current page (initially it is 1)
maxSize = maximum pagination button
itemsPerPage = perpage numbers of record to show
```

**Set below in your controller, where you are getting list of data**

```
$scope.totalItems = $scope.empList.length;
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
$scope.maxSize = 5;
```

Below put in your HTML

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
```

Comment: This is working perfectly for me.But the problem is if I edit something on the page,after navigation the i cannot see the edited value it is coming back to the first state.

Comment: for this you need to store the edited data page number then you need to assign it to `$scope.currentPage`

Comment: suppose I hide an element(say img1) in page1 using hide() method. Then I navigate to page2 did some operation and came back to page1 there the img1 is visible.